# Add Azure Web App diagnostic log settings to ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I'm looking for the option to enable diagnostic log settings (file level, not blob) on the template deployment stage.
I've found the following [example](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/ARMTemplates/WebAppManyFeatures.json) on Github however, it doesn't work, saying `"Microsoft.Web/sites/logs" is not a valid option"`.
Below is the part of my template:

```
{
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "logs",
          "type": "config",
          "location": "[resourcegroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('siteName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "applicationLogs": {
              "fileSystem": {
                "level": "Verbose"
              }
            },
            "httpLogs": {
              "fileSystem": {
                "retentionInMb": 100,
                "retentionInDays": 90,
                "enabled": true
              }
            },
            "failedRequestsTracing": {
              "enabled": true
            },
            "detailedErrorMessages": {
              "enabled": true
            }
          }
        },
```

Also, I've found the [following](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/716b1d6c-6bff-4b39-ada0-727330d014b5/azure-arm-diagnostic-logs-settings?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) discussion on a similar question but the topic starter stated that this piece of code works correctly in most cases.

Comment: create this resource in the portal and examine it in the resource explorer.

Comment: Really, I forgot about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to enable diagnostic log settings during deployment Azure WebApp. You could use the follow **demo code** to do that. It works correctly on my side.

**Deploy.json**

```
{
      "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "parameters": {
        "siteName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "appServicePlanName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "siteLocation": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "workerSize": {
          "type": "string",
          "allowedValues": [
            "0",
            "1",
            "2"
          ],
          "defaultValue": "1"
        }
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "[parameters('appServicePlanName')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
          "location": "[parameters('siteLocation')]",
          "sku": {
            "name": "S1",
            "tier": "Standard",
            "capacity": 1
          },
          "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('appServicePlanName')]"
          }
        },
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
          "location": "[parameters('siteLocation')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('appServicePlanName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "serverFarmId": "[parameters('appServicePlanName')]"
          },
          "resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
              "name": "logs",
              "type": "config",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('siteName'))]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "applicationLogs": {
                  "fileSystem": {
                    "level": "Verbose"
                  }
                },
                "httpLogs": {
                  "fileSystem": {
                    "retentionInMb": 100,
                    "retentionInDays": 90,
                    "enabled": true
                  }
                },
                "failedRequestsTracing": {
                  "enabled": true
                },
                "detailedErrorMessages": {
                  "enabled": true
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

**parameters.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "siteName": {
      "value": "xxxxxx"
    },
    "appServicePlanName": {
      "value": "xxxx"
    },
    "siteLocation": {
      "value": "East US"
    },
    "workerSize": {
      "value": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

**Check from the Azure portal.**

[image]

Comment: I've managed my deploy using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites) link, however, it doesn't have any information about `applicationLogs` or `httpLogs` so thank you for pointing me.