# Incorrect segment lengths in ARM template

Tags: azure, templates

Following Azure Advisory Recommendation, I want to enable diagnostic settings for my app services. I added the following ARM template but keeps getting error:

```
 Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'pr-datap-cf0-config-as/Microsoft.Insights/service' for type 'providers/diagnosticSettings' at line '218' and column '41' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'. (Code:InvalidTemplate)
```

I think my type has 2 segments while name has 3. But what is the type value for diagnosticSettings of an app service?

My ARM template is as follows:

```
    {
            "type": "providers/diagnosticSettings",
            "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('appServiceName'), '/Microsoft.Insights/service')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[parameters('appServiceName')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "storageAccountId": "[parameters('diagnosticStorageAccountId')]",
                "workspaceId": "[parameters('workspaceId')]",
                "metrics": [
                    {
                        "category": "AllMetrics",
                        "enabled": true,
                        "retentionPolicy": {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "days": "[parameters('diagnosticLogsRetentionInDays')]"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "logs": [
                    {
                        "category": "AppServiceAuditLogs",
                        "enabled": true,
                        "retentionPolicy": {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "days": "[parameters('diagnosticLogsRetentionInDays')]"
                        }
                    }
                ]

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my knowledge, there is no type like `providers/diagnosticSettings`. It should be like `Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings` or `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/providers/diagnosticSettings`, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/resource-manager-diagnostic-settings) are the example templates. And to set the diagnostic setting for the app service, you can take a look at another issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314112/add-azure-web-app-diagnostic-log-settings-to-arm-template). And you can also take a look at [Enable diagnostics logging for apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs).